# Update a Mongodb document and add fields

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to update a mongodb document and add some fields but in vain
my initial document looks like this

```
 {"_id" : ObjectId("52c720e3211b6f0a258b4567"),
 "email" : "someemail@msn.com",
 "date" : ISODate("2014-01-03T20:43:15Z"),
 "number" : 0, "accessToken" : "CAAIc2knVS3oBAAWRw5iqTK6mo6BEjwJJtT8PRZBUfhLayyelcXDZBO0pTWULGNPOZAxb9ZAwWk1oQghdcqxRr5yycMvkSokU7vYn3OWQJVWFuxbHC6L6F3NvLAYCrkoPvnoZAmNZBkkvG4qXFQT46hyPrDSc7GTZA1IpxVrQHEGbrwZDZD" }
```

After Update, I want to add 2 fields to the document which are : username and password.
I've looked into documentation but it doesn't seem to treat this matter.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're working with a doctrine ODM Document object :

```
$document->setUsername($username); // $document is your document instance
$document->setPassword($password);
$dm->flush($document); // $dm : document manager
```

If you want a standalone query (through QueryBuilder) :

```
$dm->createQueryBuilder('YourBundle:YourDocumentClass')
    ->field('_id')->Equals("52c720e3211b6f0a258b4567")
    ->update()
    ->field('username')->set($username)
    ->field('password')->set($password)
    ->getQuery()->execute();
```

More info and querybuilder examples here :

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html

Comment: I tried your first part of answer but it doesn't seem to work, I think it set value of name field if it does exist.

Comment: Yes, this is a requirement, the field should be properly declared in your schema and the corresponding setter methods generated. If for some reason you cannot or do not want to do it, use the querybuilder instead.

Comment: The field is in the Schema & what I meant is : the fields to add should have some values then you update them, but if they don't exist in the mongo document they can't be created.
does this make sense ?

Comment: Since the two fields are not persisted , I think I should persist them , I'll try that and give you my feedback
Feedback : it doesn't work

Comment: If you want to manipulate them through the document, then yes, you definitely need to have them persisted :-) This is what persistence is all about by the way. Let me know if I can clarify further.

Comment: Yes it seems that they need to be persisted, but again there is this $set operator in mongodb, I'm not familiar with Doctrine ODM , can you tell me how can I use $set operator in the xontext of doctrine ? 
Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: basically $set is meant to distinguish an update query which only handles a subset of the fields of a given document, from an update query which updates the whole document in one swoop. You don't need to worry about it when working with the odm, since it performs the queries for you, it will decide the most apropriate query method to apply. (Actually in both examples above a $set update will be performed)

Answer (score 1):

In the mongo shell you could do it like this:

```
db.myusers.update(
    {_id: ObjectId("52c720e3211b6f0a258b4567")}, // identify document
    {$set: {username: 'scott', password: 'tiger'} })
```

This leaves the other fields untouched.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time !
How about doctrine and symfony2 ?

Comment: Just apply `$set` to your context.

Comment: do you advise me to use querybuilder ?

Comment: Actually you should look at my answer for a doctrine ODM implementation of the same query. (remember that the ODM is an abstraction layer, you don't perform queries directly through it, instead you explain what you want to do and it performs queries on your behalf)